# Escaping string in json dictionary python request

Tags: python, json, string, python-requests

So I've got a python application that is using requests.post to make a post request with json headers, body info, etc.

Problem is that in my dictionary that gets sent as headers, I have a variable that often contains character groups like %25"" or "%2F", etc. I've seen this cause problems before if sent in body data, but that can be fixed by sending the body data as a sting rather than a dictionary. Haven't figured out how to make this work with the headers though, as you can't simply delimit the parameters with an ampersand like in body data.

How do I make sure that my cookie value is not altered in the process of the post request?

For instance, headers :
Host : blahblah.com
Connection : Keep-Alive
Cookie : ***My sensitive string with special characters***
etc.

Note : Nothing server-side can be changed. The python application is being used for hired pentesting services.

Comment: With the clarifying edit, you'll need to determine where your request is going wrong (if it is), and should almost-certainly run your own service to test in addition to getting permission from the client to investigate their servers. Additionally, one of (dependent on your use case/testing) may be the answer you're looking for: 1) dedicated library for escaping 2) raw strings `r'data'` 3) send the data as a binary stream 4) write your own wrapper or wrapper program around something like libcurl and call it

Answer (score 2):

A common technique for sending data that becomes a mess when transmitted is to encode it, especially as `base64`

Sender:

```
import base64
...
encoded_data = "base64:{}".format(base64.b64encode(data))
```

Receiver:

```
import base64
...
if encoded_data.startswith("base64:"):
    data = base64.b64decode(encoded_data.split(':')[1])
```